# mapply on subset of lists

Tags: r, sapply, mapply

I'm trying to an operation on dates using two lists of `data.frames` using `mapply` or `sapply`. Here are my two lists:

```
list_1 <- list(a=data.frame(date=c("2017-01-01","2017-02-02"),v1=1:2,
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
               b=data.frame(date=c("2017-03-03","2017-04-04"),v1=3:4,
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
list_2 <- list(a=data.frame(date=c("2018-01-01","2018-02-02"),v1=1:2,
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
               b=data.frame(date=c("2018-03-03","2018-04-04"),v1=3:4,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
```

I'd like to apply a function on the date columns using both lists. For this example, let's use `difftime`. I'd like to get a `list` of `difftime` of the date columns in list_1 and list_2. The result would look like this:

```
$a
  difftime
1 365
2 365

$b
  difftime
1 365
2 365
```

I have tried to make subsets of the lists to keep only the date columns using:

```
subset_list_1 <- lapply(list_1, "[", 1)
subset_list_2 <- lapply(list_2, "[", 1)
```

However, the result is still a `data.frame`. For some reason, the `drop=TRUE` that is usually applied with `"["` did not happen.

```
> str(subset_list_1)
List of 2
 $ a:'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ date: chr [1:2] "2017-01-01" "2017-02-02"
 $ b:'data.frame':  2 obs. of  1 variable:
  ..$ date: chr [1:2] "2017-03-03" "2017-04-04"
```

I then tried `mapply` and `sapply`, but I suspect that it throws an error because I'm not feeding vectors to `difftime`.

```
mapply(difftime,subset_list_1,subset_list_2,SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
Error in as.POSIXct.default(time1) : 
  do not know how to convert 'time1' to class “POSIXct”

sapply(subset_list_2,difftime,subset_list_1)
Error in as.POSIXct.default(time1) : 
  do not know how to convert 'time1' to class “POSIXct”
```

In other words, I'm trying to do the following but with `mapply` or `sapply`:

```
difftime(unclass(subset_list_2[[1]])$date,unclass(subset_list_1[[1]])$date)
Time differences in days
[1] 365 365
difftime(unclass(subset_list_2[[2]])$date,unclass(subset_list_1[[2]])$date)
Time differences in days
[1] 365 365
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to extract as a `vector` using `[[` instead of `[`

```
Map(function(...) data.frame(difftime = as.numeric(difftime(...))), 
                lapply(list_1, `[[`, 1), lapply(list_2, `[[`, 1))
```